# how will back button work in iPhone whithout using navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

### #

I have two view named FirstView and Second View. Now I have one button in SecondView. If i click this button then i want to move FirstView. What is the code for it?

- I don't want Navigation Bar.
- And My button should work as a "Back" Button.

### #

Comment: is your view UIViewController ?

Comment: yup dude. i used UiViewcontroller. can you have any idea then please post the example code.

Answer (score 2):

You could still use a **UINavigationController**, but hiding the navigation bar with calling

`[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:true animated:false];`

in the second view's **viewDidLoad** method.

Then just show the second view by pushing it on the navigation stack in the first view:

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:true];`

and pop it from the stack when your button is pressed in the second view:

`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];`

Answer (score 0):

Add SecondView as subview of FirstView. To go back, in the action method of back button, you could remove it from parent view.
In firstView :

```
[self addSubview:secondView];
```

In secondView :

```
- (IBAction)backButtonClicked:(id)sender {
   [self removeFromSuperview];
  }
```

Comment: manali thank you so much. but is there any other method for back method?